# How to enter the cheat code for Just Dance 3 on PS3

Tags: ps3, cheats, just-dance-3

According to the WIkipedia entry on [Just Dance 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Dance_3#Track_listing) there's an un-lockable song by entering a cheat-code into the title screen which I've found (but can't test) is the famous ↑↑↓↓←→←→

But, I don't know how to enter this into the title screen as the game is Move only. I tried using my Dualshock 3, but it's apparently not accepting the button presses (and I checked that the controller works, too).

Does anyone know how to unlock this song?

Answer (score 1):

The Barbra Striesand extreme choreography ↑↑↓↓←→←→ should be entered with the controller.

Maybe you should try again. :/

Comment: I've seen this exact same advice in multiple places.